# How to stop ubuntu pop-up "Daemons using outdated libraries" when using apt to install or update packages?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have newly installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS recently and I found that every time when I using apt to install or update packages, it will ask me about `Which service should be restarted ?`, I don't konw which should be restared and actually I don't want to restart any service when I'm using it.

This annoys me and I want to know how to disable this when using apt in Ubuntu 22?

[image]

Comment: Why is this the default in minimal ubuntu? So stupid...

Comment: Why does SE insist on closing useful questions that help the public?

Comment: @JesseNickles: it doesn't - the problem is that some *users* reflexively downvote or vote to close. This is a good question, but on the wrong site - it should have been on AskUbuntu or serverfault. The original voters should have voted to migrate. The problem now is that you can't migrate old questions, and lots of reps would be changed (lost), so this question (and lots of other good ones) are effectively zombies.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is new in Ubuntu 22.04. The trouble in this case is with the needrestart command, which is part of the apt-get upgrade process in Ubuntu now. By default this is set to "interactive" mode which causes the interruption of scripts.

To change this behavior, we can edit the /etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf file, changing the line:

```
#$nrconf{restart} = 'i';
```

to

`$nrconf{restart} = 'a';` (if we want to restart the services automatically) or `$nrconf{restart} = 'l'`; to simply list the services that need restart.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367139/apt-get-upgrade-auto-restart-services

Comment: Doesn't sound like as if scripts are interrupted because of that:
`# ATTENTION: If needrestart is configured to run in interactive mode but is run
# non-interactive (i.e. unattended-upgrades) it will fallback to list only mode.` (Comment is from needrestart.conf)

Comment: Here's the command that you are looking for: `sed "/#\$nrconf{restart} = 'i';/s/.*/\$nrconf{restart} = 'a';/" /etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf`

Comment: I forgot to add the `-i` in the sed command in order to automatically edit the file instead of outputting the result to the standard output. So the entire command would be: `sed -i "/#\$nrconf{restart} = 'i';/s/.*/\$nrconf{restart} = 'a';/" /etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf`

Comment: Does anyone know anything to avoid all these alerts in the terminal? I just want text there. My SSH application often has problems with these interfaces.

Comment: To avoid modifying package file, its recommended to put this option in `conf.d` directory, for example `/etc/needrestart/conf.d/90-autorestart.conf`